# cmake list subcommand do not recognize ;-separated list

Tags: cmake

Using CMake 3.9, I have some strange issue with list() subcommands.
The following code snippet

```
foreach(__lib ${_blas})
    message(STATUS "DEBUG: before ${__lib}")
endforeach()
message(STATUS "DEBUG: before ${_blas}")
list(LENGTH _blas len)
message("_blas has length ${len}")
```

gives the following output:

-- DEBUG: before -Wl,--start-group

-- DEBUG: before /share/sw/licensed/intel/pstudio_xe_cluster-2015/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a

-- DEBUG: before /share/sw/licensed/intel/pstudio_xe_cluster-2015/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a

-- DEBUG: before /share/sw/licensed/intel/pstudio_xe_cluster-2015/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a

-- DEBUG: before -Wl,--end-group

-- DEBUG: before -lpthread

-- DEBUG: before -lm

-- DEBUG: before -Wl,--start-group;/share/sw/licensed/intel/pstudio_xe_cluster-2015/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a;/share/sw/licensed/intel/pstudio_xe_cluster-2015/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a;/share/sw/licensed/intel/pstudio_xe_cluster-2015/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a;-Wl,--end-group;-lpthread;-lm

_blas has length 0

For some reason, `foreach()` recognize _blas as list and `list()` subcommand does not. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: _blas is a **macro argument** and thus can not be used in a list command.